# Python Selenium doesn't get all elements of webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get runners' data from this webpage: http://results.nyrr.org/event/M2016/finishers. I know that the easy approach of using a `requests.get` or `requests.post` don't work here, so I tried to use selenium and webdriver. I wrote the following code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://results.nyrr.org/event/M2016/finishers')
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find("div", attrs={"ng-show": "eventFinishers.length > 0"})
table2 = table.findAll("div", {"class": "cmd-finisher ng-scope", "ng-repeat": "eventFinisher in eventFinishers"})
```

The problem is that I don't get exactly the same information that is provided in the web and that I can see in Chrome Developer Tools.
For instance, for the first runner, I don't get the place in the Gender cathegory. It should say 1, but I see it as empty. However, I get the name "Gender Place". The same happens for age-group, overall gun place, team, and other information:

```
>>> print(table2[0].text)
Ghirmay Ghebreslassie
M20
ERI
Place: 1
Pace: 04:53
Bib: 2
View Runner's Page
Expand Results
Expand
2:07:51
2:07:51
Gender/Age:M20

Team:
Official Time
2:07:51
Pace Per Mile
04:53
Overall Place
1
Gender Place
Age-Group Place
Overall Gun Place
Age-Graded Time
Age-Graded Place
Age-Graded %
NaN%
View in Graph
Go To Runner's Page
Compare this runner
Request Corrections
Close
Created with Highcharts 4.2.1Chart titleHighcharts.com
Go back to detail view
```

Also, using this code I was not able to get the information under the names of "5K split", "10k split"...

I have checked that this information is not in `html = browser.page_source` , so the problem might be that webdriver is not loading the webpage correctly. Is it possible to get the information I want using selenium-webdriver?
 How can I solve this? If it is not possible, what other alternatives do I have? (I'm using python 3)

Comment: Find span element that contains place using following: `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Place:")]')`. After that get text from that element and replace "Place: " in that string. This will leave you with place number.

Comment: "Also, using this code I was not able to get the information under the names of "5K split", "10k split"..."      The information only loads when you click in "Expand Results", find them all, click at each one and get what you need. To click on one of them you can do: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` and then `browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".col-xs-3.col-sm-3.col-md-3.expand-box").click()`

Comment: @sen4ik, if I do that for "Gender Place", I cannot get the place number.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar, that works! Thank you! Just one additional question: if I have to download the 51,275 results, do I need to click all of them at the same time? Is there a more efficienty way to do it?

Comment: hmm I don't know if there is a more efficient way to deal with this, loading them all at once will definetely crash the browser.